# Unable to connect to Azure Virtual Machine via RDP

Tags: azure, ssh, virtual-machine, rdp

I created a virtual machine on Azure using CentOS 7. I've tried it using 2 different images. I suspect it has something to do with me having multiple ssh keys. I was able to ssh in by specifying the key, `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa antarr@0.0.0.0`. I copied the other key using `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/other antarr@0.0.0.0` and I'm able to ssh in without specify which key to use now. But when trying to connect using RDP, I get a connection refused error. I have verified that the RDP, port is configured on the VM.

#### Security Rules

[image: Security Rules]

Comment: Do you open RDP port in NSG(usually subnet level or NIC level), you can check it from virtual machine->networking on the Azure portal.

Comment: @NancyXiong I'm going the guess NSG, the name of the name of network security group ends with `-nsg`

Comment: What do you see in the Boot Diagnostics (waiting for console or do you see any entries) 
Can you post the screen shot of complete error thrown during connection?
Have you tried to reset your SSH configuration?

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT There is nothing to screenshot the client just says 'connection refused'. I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop, tried version 8 and 10, on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/antarr/956d72dd1737f88342a5ec2d6eb71980) to the boot diagnostics. Any yes I've tried reseting the SSH configuration.

Comment: @NancyXiong I've added a screenshot of the security rules.

Comment: Is this NSG attached to subnet or NIC? If you have both NSGs, you need to open these ports in both Inbound security rules. Verify if the outbound 3389 is open in your client PC on a MacBook Pro. Or try to RDP from a windows client in the same on-premise network?

Comment: Can you try the suggestion mentioned in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop it''s XRDP

Comment: @NancyXiong It say `Associated with: 0 subnets, 1 network interfaces`

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT I followed that an restarted the machine but still can't connect via RDP

Comment: @NancyXiong I don't have a windows machine

Comment: FYI 1) This question belongs on SuperUser, not Stack Overflow and 2) the Comments are not the place for a long discussion, which this comment section has turned into. Feel free to edit your question to add any details you've posted in comments, and then delete those comments. Likewise, for others commenting, please remove any comments that are not valuable anymore, per responses.

Comment: I was able to get it working by following this this tutorial [How to enable Desktop Experience and enable RDP for a CentOs 7 VM on Microsoft Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_azure_guide/2015/01/05/how-to-enable-desktop-experience-and-enable-rdp-for-a-centos-7-vm-on-microsoft-azure/)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-ssh-connection) helps you find and correct the problems that occur due to Secure Shell (SSH) errors, SSH connection failures, or SSH is refused when you try to connect to a Linux virtual machine (VM). You can use the Azure portal, Azure CLI, or VM Access Extension for Linux to troubleshoot and resolve connection problems.

Refer to [Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-connection)

[This blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_azure_guide/2015/01/05/how-to-enable-desktop-experience-and-enable-rdp-for-a-centos-7-vm-on-microsoft-azure/) describes the steps to How to enable Desktop Experience and enable RDP for a CentOs 7 VM on Microsoft Azure